# What to prepare first, the fries or the burger? How to serve everything crispy and warm?

Tags: temperature, hamburgers, french-fries

I'll be serving 4 burgers (medium rare, toasted buns, choice of cheese, onions, lettuce, etc.) with fries. I can use the oven to keep some of these things warm and crisp, how should I go about it? What sequence, what temp?
Thank you!

Comment: Proper fries, from scratch (double cooked..etc.)? How are you cooking both?

Comment: So, who's good with GANTT charts?

Comment: It would help to know the cooking methods you plan to use

Comment: Without knowing how you're cooking these, and your skill level (including your comfort with multitasking) there isn't really anything more that can be said beyond "think about how long each element takes, and work backwards from your desired finish time".

Answer (score 6):

My instinct is that you should have everything cook at the same time. Cut all veggies and make sure fries are pre cooked so the second frying is for exterior crispness. You should be able to drop fries while burgers are cooking. I would put burger down, drop fries, flip burger, pull fries, toast bun and then plate everything. Working to your ability.